# com.android.phone stopped working

Tags: java, android, xml

Hi just now start building small applications in Android.I tried to initiate a call on button click by calling Call Intent. I have set the necessary permissions in Manifest file.

But still I am getting error message as

***com.android.phone stopped working***

[image]

```
<Linear Layout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnShow"
    android:text="@string/btnShow"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif" />

      </LinearLayout>
```

MainActvity.java

```
package com.example.androidproject2;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnShowDialer=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
        btnShowDialer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            try
            { Intent callIntent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:1121121212"));
                startActivity(callIntent);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Trail","Call Falied", e);
            }

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Log Output

```
08-08 09:29:28.378: D/gralloc_goldfish(862): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-08 09:29:37.548: D/AndroidRuntime(862): Shutting down VM
08-08 09:29:37.608: W/dalvikvm(862): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method showDialer(View) in the activity class com.example.androidproject2.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btnShow'
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3620)
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: showDialer [class android.view.View]
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:423)
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:787)
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3613)
08-08 09:29:37.688: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  ... 11 more
08-08 09:39:06.209: D/gralloc_goldfish(931): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-08 09:39:23.398: I/Choreographer(931): Skipped 82 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-08 09:39:26.398: I/Choreographer(931): Skipped 110 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Post your Logcat output.

Comment: In your `xml` do you really have exactly this: `<Linear Layout` - ? Because if so, you'll have problems like the above :) You should have `<LinearLayout` (one string).

Comment: The Phone application crashes or your app? You can't do anything if it's the phone app; maybe you're sending wrong params or the permissions are not set right?

Comment: no @g00dy it is LinearLayout only

Comment: no @gunar it is my application only not phone app

Comment: have you add permission in manifest file?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
This one I have added

Answer (score 1):

try like

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1121121212"));
                startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: +1 from me, I was just about to ask if he/she has it in the manifest:)

Comment: ya added but still issue remains

Comment: In Error Log: I got IOEXCEPTION from Virtual Machine

Comment: @MadhavanNR try on real device !

Answer (score 0):

The Logcat message and your Layout are not from the same run.

The Logcat error clearly says:

> Could not find a method showDialer(View) in the activity class com.example.androidproject2.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btnShow'

That means that your real Layout is not what you are posting here. I am pretty sure it contains something like this:

```
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btnShow"
    android:text="@string/btnShow"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:onClick="showDialer" />
```

Note the **android:onClick="showDialer"**, that is what Logcat is telling you.

Either delete that line from the Layout, or create the method showDialer and delete the setOnClickListener().